# Activemq vs rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-mvc, message-queue, spring-jms, spring-amqp

I have read a few discussions and forums but still fail to understand which one is better rabbitmq vs activemq. I have heard the delay in rabbitmq is more because all traffic is first diverted to a central node. It would be good if someone can point me to some documentation which can highlight what one should use in what scenario. Thanks all

Comment: This is an excellent resource for this (which includes a number of other related technologies as well) and is much more recent (18 July 2017): [Evaluating persistent, replicated message queues](https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on ActiveMQ for 3 years and currently working on RabbitMQ.
I would suggest you to go with RabbitMQ for lightweight messaging broker with good messaging features. Most Importantly RabbitMQ has **good community support and goes well with popular frameworks such as Spring boot**.

It just takes me 10 mins to fully setup a working messaging system using Spring AMQP and RabbitMQ.

Comment: Reasons for your choice?

Answer (score -1):

### RabbitMQ vs ActiveMQ

**Architecture:**

RabbitMQ uses an AMQP (Advanced Message Queuing Protocol) based architecture while ActiveMQ uses a JMS (Java Message Service) based architecture.

**Scalability:**

RabbitMQ is designed for better scalability as compared to ActiveMQ, as it is built on top of the Erlang programming language which is known for its efficient handling of concurrent connections.

**Performance:**

RabbitMQ is generally faster than ActiveMQ, as it uses a multi-threaded, non-blocking architecture that enables it to handle large numbers of concurrent connections with low latency.

**Integration:**

RabbitMQ is known for its ease of integration with other systems and languages, while ActiveMQ provides a wider range of integration options due to its JMS architecture.

**Management:**

RabbitMQ provides a comprehensive management console that allows users to monitor and control the messaging broker, while ActiveMQ provides a web-based administration console.